# Different ways of destructuring props in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have seen two ways to destructure props in React.

```
    function MyComponent({name,age,height}){
            // do stuff here
    }
```

or

```
    function MyComponent(props){
            const {name,age,height} = props
            // do stuff here
    }
```

Suppose this component is used as

`<MyComponent name="bob" age={25} height = {175} haspets={false}/>`

Here is my questions:

If I used the first way of destructuring, does it mean that I will have no access to other props, in this case `haspets`

What are some pros/cons of these two ways?

Comment: All you have to add is add that prop to the list `function MyComponent({name,age,height,haspets})` if you need to use it

Comment: You can also do `function MyComponent({name,age,height,...others})`. In that case rest of the props (in your case `haspets` ) pass will be available in `others` as an object

Comment: Thanks, I asked the question because I didn't want to do too much excessive destructuring

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but since it's really a matter of preference and largely contextual it's not a great fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you destructure your props from the function parameters, you won't be able to access any other `props` later on**, so your assumption is correct. As far as performance and other pros/cons though, these forms are pretty much identical. I happen to like this way, because I like as few additional variable declarations in my files as possible. It can, be a pain with functions that require lots of props.

**Unless you use the spread operator and store them in a separate variable.

Comment: Technically since this hypothetical functional component is being defined with the `function` keyword you can access `arguments` within the function body. Props are passed in as the first argument, so `arguments[0]` contains all of your props, regardless of what you destructure in the parameters list. Useful in a pinch!

Comment: Right, but this won't work with Arrow functions and I feel like is considered poor practice.

Answer (score 8):

You can have access on the other properties of your object later, throught [the arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), though as also pointed out on the link the rest parameters should be prefered.

```js
<MyComponent name="bob" age={25} height = {175} surname="test" haspets={false} />

function MyComponent({ name, age, height, ...rest }){
      // rest will be an object like { surname: 'test', haspets: false }
}
```

One of the differences I can think of, and I suppose the **most important**, is that on the second case, while you are destructing your `props` object, you are using `const` on declaration.

In that way, you can no longer change these values on your `MyComponent`, while on your first case you could easily modify them.

Comment: I thought props can be modified by parent components who passed them down anyway. I don't think a component can modify it's own props though.

Comment: It shouldn't be modified, but it can when there is nothing preventing it by doing so. You can take a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-sky-h3768. 

I'm just pointing a differnce between those two approaches that you've listed on your question, while I find myself using both of them equally.

Comment: ok I see, so it will be like a local variable. Hence won't cause rerender and will be reset to whatever value passed to it whenever a rerender happens